# undefined control sequence error while writing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I am trying to write algorithm but got errors like

> undefined control sequence..

my code is given below can anyone tell why I am getting this error and how to remove

```
 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{algorithm} 
     \usepackage{algorithmic}
     
    %package for multi affiliations
    %\usepackage{authblk}
    \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \begin{document}
    
     \begin{algorithm}[t]
     \caption{\name\ Algorithm}
    \label{alg:algo1} 
     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
     \REQUIRE bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
     \ENSURE  eeeeeeeeeeeee
     \\ \textit{ttttttttttt}   
    \STATE gggggggggggggggggggggg
    \\\textit{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj} 
            \FOR{ $user$  \(i\in n\) in $p$}  
              \STATE  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
              \STATE   dddddddddddddddd
            \ENDFOR
    \STATE tttttttttttttttt
    \STATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
     \\ \textit{vvvvvvvvvvv}
    \STATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    \STATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
    \\ \textit{bbbbbbbbbbbb}
    \STATE bbbbbbbbbbbb
    
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the resulting error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ignorespaces \name 
                               \ Algorithm
```

That ment that the command `\name` is undefined. Define it or use simply a name in line 19 in your code. Change

```
     \caption{\name\ Algorithm} % <======================== undefined \name
```

to

```
     \caption{name\ Algorithm} % <======================== undefined \name
```

The following mwe compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 
%package for multi affiliations
%\usepackage{authblk}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

 \begin{algorithm}[t]
 \caption{\name\ Algorithm} % <======================== undefined \name
\label{alg:algo1} 
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
 \REQUIRE bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 \ENSURE  eeeeeeeeeeeee
 \\ \textit{ttttttttttt}   
\STATE gggggggggggggggggggggg
\\\textit{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj} 
        \FOR{ $user$  \(i\in n\) in $p$}  
          \STATE  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
          \STATE   dddddddddddddddd
        \ENDFOR
\STATE tttttttttttttttt
\STATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
 \\ \textit{vvvvvvvvvvv}
\STATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
\STATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
\\ \textit{bbbbbbbbbbbb}
\STATE bbbbbbbbbbbb

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```